# Safari doesn't render modal windows

Tags: css, safari

I am using the "just me" effect from [**here**](http://tympanus.net/Development/ModalWindowEffects/), however I am having problems with Safari v5.1, it just doesn't render the modal. When inspecting I can see that the modal should be there but it just stays transparent. Is there any trick to force the browser to re-render?

EDIT: I have also checked the css properties that are being used and they are supported.

EDIT2: Here's the link in case it's hard to see http://tympanus.net/Development/ModalWindowEffects/ , I am using exactly the same code and the highest z-index.

Comment: It's hard for us to help you with only a description of your problem.  Transparent could mean anything...  Please provide a code sample of your modal including HTML and CSS and any related Javascript/jQuery you might be using.

My guess is that the z-index is too low and the modal is not appearing "above" the rest of the page.  But that's only a guess.

Comment: Maybe you couldn't see the link, I'm using exactly the same code as the the link I have provided, here's the link again just in case: http://tympanus.net/Development/ModalWindowEffects/ try clicking "just me"

Also the z-index is really high(1k+) so it's not that either

Comment: I saw the link, and can see their code.  Their code obviously works fine.  I can't see YOUR code which evidently doesn't work.  See my point?  A live link to your site would help as well.

Comment: It's a localhost, the reason I'm giving the link is because when I open it in safari 5.1.7 it has exactly the same problem as mine(doesn't render at all)

Comment: What version of Safari are you using and are you on PC or Mac?

Comment: I'm using 5.1.7 on Windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To anybody interested: 
In this case the transition is `transition: all .3s ease;`  but Safari has problem when it has to transition opacity and visibility at the same time. Changing to `transition: opacity .3s ease, transform .3s ease;` (with all necessary prefixes) fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

```
.faded{
  opacity: 1;
}
```

This worked for me.